# Sum manipulation

Tags: summation, arithmetic

my question is if these two sums are equal:

$\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda u_jx_j + \mu v_j x_j = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda u_jx_j + \sum_{j=1}^n \mu v_jx_j$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are asking whether $(a+b)+(c+d)+(e+f)$ is equal to $(a+c+e)+(b+d+f)$.

Comment: Is $n$ a finite number?

Comment: @YuriyS yes it is

Comment: Then yes, for any finite sum the associative property is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)=\sum_{i=1}^na_i+\sum_{i=1}^nb_i$$

We can check it by using mathematical induction.

- Check base case
- Suppose it is true for $n-1$ terms.

\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_i+b_i)\right)+(a_n+b_n) \\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}b_i\right)+(a_n+b_n)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i + \left( \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}b_i\right)+(a_n+b_n)\right) \text{,associative}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i + \left( \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}b_i\right)+(b_n+a_n)\right) \text{,commutative}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i + \left( \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}b_i+b_n\right)+a_n\right) \text{,associative}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i + \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i+a_n\right) \end{align}

I am leaving the last few steps for exercise.

Comment: @Mathmeeeeen Why don't you accept this answer? You have asked several questions on this site and received several answers, but *none of them* was accepted.